# change the binlog-row-image property in AWS Aurora MySQL instance to enable change data capture

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I'm new to Amazon Aurora and want to use it to replace an on-prem MySQL instance. We're performing change data capture via MySQL's binlog in our on-prem instance.

In order to do this, it was necessary to set a couple of properties in `/etc/my.cnf`:

```
binlog_format     = row
binlog-row-image  = full
```

I notice that it's possible to create a custom parameter group. Unfortunately, it appears that the `binlog-row-image` property is not modifiable. An error is thrown when I try to change it:

[image]

Is there some other mechanism to update this property outside of the custom parameter group? I notice that its 'Apply type' is dynamic. Does that mean this particular property can be edited permanently at runtime? If so, what's the command?

**edit:**

I set the dynamic `binlog_format` property by executing the following:

```
SET binlog_row_image = 'full';
```

This could be the answer... testing now.

**edit:**

As @BillKarwin correctly points out, the command should be:

```
SET GLOBAL binlog_row_image = 'full';
```

Unfortunately, the master user doesn't have permissions to execute this command:

```
[42000][1227] Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

Does that mean that CDC that depends on the `binlog_row_image` property is impossible on Aurora MySQL?

Comment: You should `set global` if you do that at all, otherwise it applies only to binlog events created by your current session, and your setting will go away once you close the connection. But `set global` depends on SUPER privilege, which I'm sure Aurora does not grant.

Comment: You should check to see if AWS provides a stored procedure that can change the global binlog_row_image. They provide a set of procedures that you can call to perform specific tasks that would otherwise require SUPER privilege. For example, here's the list for RDS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.MySQL.SQLRef.html But I don't know if this list applies for Aurora as well. I'd recommend you contact AWS support to confirm.

Comment: Thanks again, @BillKarwin. Really appreciated.

Comment: This value can't be changed on Aurora... but have you verified that Aurora doesn't *already* log what you need, regardless of how it is set?

Comment: That's an interesting question, @Michael-sqlbot. I have not spent time looking around the various internal tables. I'll take a look.